# focus on textarea that display error message

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have number of textarea displayed using forloop and also checked whether textarea contains minimum number of words that required.Error message displayed if textbox does not contain minimum number of words. How can I focus on the textbox which displays error

I am using angular 2

html

```
 <span *ngSwitchCase="'fileupload_with_textarea'">
               <textarea  autosize [value]='question.value'  class="form-control"    max-word-count maxlen=
               {{question.word_details.maximum_word}} minlen=
               {{question.word_details.minimum_word}}  [formControlName]="question.key"  [id]="question.key" (blur)="focusOutSave(question)" #message></textarea>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="question.controlType == 'fileupload_with_textarea' && page_submit && !form.controls[question.key].valid && form.controls[question.key].touched">You didn't enter the answer.</div>
            </span>
```

component

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, Directive,AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, ViewChild ,ViewChildren ,ElementRef ,ChangeDetectorRef, HostListener}  from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'dynamic-form',
    templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
    providers: [ QuestionControlService, SweetAlertService],
    styles: [
    `
      :host >>> .tooltip-inner {
        background-color: #f88f5a;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      :host >>> .tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow:before,
      :host >>> .tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
        border-top-color: #f88f5a;
      }
    `
  ]
 })


export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];

    @Input() input_params: any;
    @Input() other_vars:any;


    @Input() question_loading_status:boolean;
    @Output() outputEvent:EventEmitter<QuestionBase<any>[]>=new EventEmitter();


    @Input() enrolment_detail_id: number;
    @Output() getQuestions  = new EventEmitter();
    @ViewChild('message') public message: ElementRef;


//onsubmit
 if (this.form.controls[question.key]['wordCt'] != undefined) { 
                if(this.form.controls[question.key]['wordCt'].wordFlag == false && wordCountFlag){
                    wordCountFlag = 0;
                    this.message.nativeElement.focus();
                }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use ElementRef to get the reference to hative HTML element, and use it's focus() method.

In your template component:

```
<textarea
   #messageInput
></textarea>
```

your component:

```
@ViewChild('messageInput') public messageInput: ElementRef;
```

In your validation code, you can call native focus method on the textarea like this:

```
this.messageInput.nativeElement.focus();
```

Comment: It shows ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined  why this error shows..? i tried this code all time it shows the same error

Comment: can you post your component's code and template here?

Comment: added to question Thank you

Comment: Can you show exactly how you handle submit? That could be the reason why `nativeElement` is undefined

Comment: in component there is a function submitForMarking() that calls when click on submit

Comment: Are you sure your textarea is rendered? Since it's inside of ngSwitchCase. You can try adding console.log(this.message) inside of `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook to debug it.

Comment: sorry ... there is a problem textarea and submit are in different component . how can I solve this. all text area are in diffrent component and submit is in another component

Comment: it depends how your components are structured, but you could use @Output event emitter (like you already have - outputEvent), and emit an event on submit. The parent component can listen to this event and trigger focus on textarea element.